# How can I retrieve the real password from a hashed password?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

I want to create a hybrid mobile application where the backend is Node js that it will save data in mongodb. my server works properly and I prepared routes for handling users requests.

I'm using bcrypt to store password hashes in mongodb. Passwords are saved correctly but my problem that I can't retrieve the real password, for example, when admin pass a GET request to node js server in order to get user data, he get the hashed password in the front-end.

this is the result in the front-end:

[image]

this is the code to store password hashes :

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

Please how can I retrieve the real password?

Comment: The whole point of storing hashed passwords is that you cannot restore the original password.

Comment: don't try to retrieve password, you can provide password, encrypt and match with already saved password.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.  By design, a hash function, especially a cryptographic hash function, is non-invertible, or a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).  Cryptographic hash functions by design have the following properties

- it is quick to compute the hash value for any given input
- **it is infeasible to generate a input from its hash value except by
  trying all possible inputs**
- **small changes to an input should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value**
- It is infeasible to find two different inputs with the same hash value

This is one of many critical pieces to secure password storage.  For example, if an attacker gains access to your server and is thus able to run arbitrary queries on your database, proper cryptographic hash functions ensure the attacker cannot retrieve your user's passwords.

Source: [Wikipedia - Cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. This is the purpose of password hashing.

Answer (score 5):

That's the point of hashing.. 'irreversably' deforming the password. If it's a plain hash, you should be able to crack it using rainbowtables or other methods of the sort. If you've used a 'salt' to hash the password, I believe the chances of you cracking the password are even more slim.

Especially bcrypt which uses the blowfish cypher, is a very potent hashing algorithm.

Hashing passwords has become a standard, so that the website owners physically don't have access to the plain passwords.

One more follow-up question: why?

Comment: Bcrypt also iterates such that the operation takes a substantial amount of time, this is the crucial point. Just hashing passwords, even with a salt is not enough to protect them, there are lists of 10M common passwords an just hashing is very fast, my laptop can execute 700K SHA-256 hashes per second. Further specialized programs to run them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. To match the entered password and the saved hash, you should hash the entered password the same way you stored it (using `bcrypt()`) and then, simply check (`==`) if they're the same.